# Can't undo disable render

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes, visibility

I keyframed the render visibility for an animation. The object was supposed to not show for first half of animation and then be rendered for the second half. However, the object never appeared again. And now I can't even toggle the render visibility (it stays disbled). I have tried to remove all keyframes connected to render visibility and restarted Blender, but I can't toggle the render visibility anyway.

I am using 2.8 and have additional keyframes on the same object for scaling.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

apparently after toggeling the other visibility options a few times it worked